How to modify spaces in the tab_model function
I have put together this table using results from a logistic regression into a tab_model (sjPlot) function. When I click to expand the table the predictors line has all the terms run together  (Odds Ratios std. Error Statistic) I've attached a picture.
I've attached the code, I've tried adding lines about line wrapping, making custom labels, and line breaking, but they don't seem to affect the predictor line.
c<- tab_model(behavehelps, behavehelp,
          transform = "exp",
show.ci = FALSE,
show.r2 = FALSE, 
show.se = TRUE,
show.stat = TRUE,
wrap.labels = 25,
linebreak = TRUE,
string.se = "std. Error",
string.stat = "Statistic",
dv.labels = c("Simple Model", "Full Model"),
pred.labels = custom_labels,
title = "Asking for Behavioral Help in the Last Six Months",
p.style = c("stars"),
p.threshold = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01))


